# Starting PalmPre2 Dev. Palm-install says: "no devices found"

Tags: webos, palm-pre, palm, palm-pre2

I am a iPhone Developer trying to start PalmPre2 development, so I am doing as written [here](http://developer.palm.com/index.php?...rticle&id=1758)

I have my emulator working and running.

I have created my workspace directory

```
$mkdir palmWorkspace
$cd palmWorkspace
```

I have create my app

```
$ palm-generate -p "{title:'Hello World', id:com.nacho4d.hello, version:'1.0.0'}" HelloWorld
generating new_app in /Users/nacho4d/Documents/palmWorkspace/HelloWorld
```

I have packaged it

```
$ palm-package Helloworld
creating package com.nacho4d.hello_1.0.0_all.ipk in /Users/nacho4d/Documents/palmWorkspace
```

but now when I try to install it I get:

```
$ palm-install com.nacho4d.hello_1.0.0_all.ipk 
palm-install: no devices found
palm-install: no device found
```

Even though I have the emulator running it says the same, why is that?

Thanks in advance.

Ignacio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to myself:

I have realized that pal-install seems not to be as fast as expected when recognizing/finding a running emulator. I mean, if you start the emulator just before running  palm-install command, this will probably fail. After a while running the same command worked as expected ;)